# Cannot add phone in settings Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, iphone, phone

I want to add my phone in Windows 10 Settings, but button "+" is not active.
Also there is yellow text in the top of the window:

```
Your organization decided to hide some of this parameters or control it
```

(I translate this text from Ukrainian, so it can not match to the English version)

> Windows 10 Education v.1909 (build 18363.657)

Please, help! :)

Comment: Does your computer belong to your work or to your school?

Comment: @WilliamV. No, this is my pc

Comment: More than likely this is happening because you have the Windows 10 Education edition installed, which provides controls for organizations like schools. Have you tried adding your phone on a PC with Windows 10 Home or Pro?

Comment: @WilliamV. Yes, before Educational I have Pro, and everything works well. So can I do something with this without reinstalling windows?

Comment: From my experience, I think you will have to switch over to Windows 10 Home or Pro.